# Do we need Hashtable since we have ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, hashtable, concurrenthashmap

Java's `java.util.Hashtable` has the same functionality as `java.util.HashMap`. Their main difference is that `Hashtable` is thread-safe and synchronized while `HashMap` is not. As of JDK5, we have `ConcurrentHashMap` which can be used for multi-thread context. It has better performance than `Hashtable`. So do we have any reason to use `Hashtable` in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse compatibility is the only reason `Hashtable` is still in the JDK.

Also, another alternative to `Hashtable` is a [`Collections.synchronziedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Comment: Since ConcurrentHashMap has better performance than synchronizedMap, do we have reasons to use synchronizedMap?

Comment: @Jacky No, the same reason applies: It *was* there before, hence it will stay there - Sun/oracle take backwards compatibility quite serious and basically never remove anything from the JDK (there are still methods in JDK7 that were misspellt in 1.0 and renamed in 1.1)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of existing interfaces that [use HashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/class-use/Hashtable.html). In most, if not all cases, these cannot be replaced without breaking compatibility.